# Azure Build Pipeline - Pause and Enable DefinitionQueueStatus change REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops

We have many dozens of build pipelines and we want to pause and resume (re-enable) build pipelines from a simple webapp interface as we are making config changes frequently. Here is the MS doc explaining this API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#definitionqueuestatus

From this documentation, it appears I need to hit the REST API and change/toggle the DefinitionQueueStatus -- however, this documentation only shows a sample for a build specific operation, whereas I want to pause then re-enable the entire build pipeline. What is the proper way to make this call?

I'm using fetch - and I've tried many dozen formats in the call - the 'ourorg' and 'ourproject' are correct (we use this call structure for many other calls), but all fails for this call below. I grabbed the 'definitionID' from the URL I can visibly see when in the Azure devops portal on the specific build pipeline page, and I'm using it for the {buildID} as I don't know what else to put there. Any guidance to help here is appreciated - I don't need to use fetch btw - any working sample will help here:

```
fetch(https://dev.azure.com/our_org/our_projectname/_apis/build/builds/definitionId=1593?retry=true&api-version=5.0 {
            method: 'PATCH ',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            body: 'DefinitionQueueStatus: "Enabled"'                
            }).then(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the body is incorrect in your post. Here is sample about how to use POSTMAN to access Azure DevOps Services REST APIs.

1. Generate the PAT, and then record the token, it is important to use to authorization, please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops).
2. Create a new request in POSTMAN, it is recommended to put the request in a collection for Azure DevOps Services REST API;
3. Select the authorization as Basic Auth, you can input the username as any value, and the password as the token which is generated in step1.
   [Basic Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOguq.png)
4. Set the REST API which you want to use,and select the request method type(GET,POST,FETCH ....), here you use `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.0`.
5. In the `Body` tab, you can set the request body as raw in json format, and input the value as following:

   ```
   {
       "buildNumber":"#20190607.2",
       "buildNumberRevision":1,
       "definition":
       {
           "id":1,
           "createdDate":null,
           "queueStatus":"paused"
       }
   }
   ```
6. Everthing is ready now, you can send the request, if sccuess, you will get the response from the REST API.

In your post, the body content is incorrect, the Request Body should meet the format in the REST API document. The DefinitionQueueStatus is a type in definitions. In addition, if you send the request with parameter `retry`, you will get the message `The request body must be empty when the retry parameter is specified.`.

Comment: Thank you for the body format - however - in your response #4, that is the sample call in the doc I commented about - it is not what we need. We need to set a pause/re-enable on the pipeline itself -- NOT on a single build. So I don't understand what {buildId} is in the call string, or why you have a specific build number and revision in the body. I don't want to send the command for a specific build. We need to be able to send this call anytime to pause the entire pipeline. Also - what is the 'id:1' in the body? Where did that come from?

Comment: Also - there is no format provided, or sample in the REST API document I posted. Perhaps you are referencing this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0    But that doc does not have the body format posted either.  Very very poor documentation and your answer only helps a bit (clarifying need for auth PAT).  Thanks for further clarification on my comment above.

Comment: Also - in the postman image you sent, you have "46" for the {buildID} - what is that?  A build has a 'number' that I can see, and the format is like this: 20190523.1    I really appreciate your help - thx Mike.

Comment: Also - looking at PAT - we already are authenticated in the browser with user credentials in the browser - so we can hit the APIs in postman without any complex auth config - are you suggesting we need to setup our call like this? We were hoping to not have to implement this complexity... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujzrq8Fg9Gc

Comment: You can use [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get the list of builds in your project. At the moment, i can not find a REST API to set a pause/re-enable on the pipeline itself. You can update the build for each in the build list.

Comment: Yes, we've been able to hit and get a list of the builds and pipelines with direct browser requests (authentication passed from browser session). However, with the Azure REST APIs the browser authentication/session is not available, and only the video I posted above shows how to structure the API call. There is not a single, accurate, even remotely helpful piece of documentation anywhere on Azure REST API with a proper sample.  We continue to feel like first customers using these services, frustrating.

Comment: @Chas, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=azure-devops) is a sample which shows how to get authenticatication Azure DevOps Services and use the REST APIs or .NET Libraries. You need to convert the PAT to basic64 string as credential.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Interesting. We want a simple web page though, so can't use .Net but I'll see if I can structure this in javascript/jquery or something. Funny - the video link I posted, and others sources seem to indicate for any Azure DevOps REST API call you need to first query ADD for a bearertoken - then you use that for a full call. But the bearer token is not the same as the PAT. But I'll give this a try. thx